# How to grep for a line containing at most one forward slash?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to get the size of the top level directories under the current directory (on Solaris).  So I'm piping du to grep and want to match only those lines that have a single forward slash ie. the top level directories.

Something like:

```
du -h | grep -e <your answer here>
```

but nothing I try works.  Help appreciated!

Comment: Consider for similar issues next time http://unix.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
grep -e '^[^/]*/[^/]*$'
```

Note that this matches lines that have exactly one (not at most one) slash, but that should be OK for your usage.

You could also probably do something with the `-s` switch

```
du -hs */
```

Comment: Yes they both work, thanks.  Although with grep, the -v option given below is a little easier to remember ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can also match the things you do not want with the -v option :

```
ptimac:Tools pti$ du | grep -v '/.*/'
22680   ./960-Grid-System
137192  ./apache-activemq-5.3.0
23896   ./apache-camel-2.0.0
386816  ./apache-servicemix-3.3.1
251480  ./apache-solr-1.4.0
345288  ./Community Edition-IC-96.SNAPSHOT.app
```

(I checked the solaris man page first now ;-)

There are other ways on GNU systems to skin that  cat without using regex :

```
find . -d1
```

finds all files/folders at a depth of 1

and a command I use often when cleaning <strike>house</strike>disk is :

```
du -d1
```

or (and this should work on Solaris too)

```
du | sort -n
```

which shows me the largest directories wherever they are below the current directory.

Comment: and then pipe that to `xargs gdu --max-depth=0`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but why don't you ask `gdu` to do that for you?

```
gdu --max-depth=1
```

If you really want to go the `grep` way, how about this?

```
du -h| grep -v '/.*/'
```

This will filter out lines with two or more slashes, leaving you with those that have one or zero.

Comment: @David: I believe `du` has a similar switch

Answer (score 0):

```
du --max-depth=1 -h
```

Comment: No --max-depth option for du on Solaris :/